# split string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, split

I am working on node js with mongodb. I am getting the value of doc in view file.

```
{{#each doc}}
    <div class="abstract" data-reactid=".1ejbmifi4u8.1.1.0.1.2.0:$35.0.0.1.2.0" id="content">
                                    {{this.content}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

this will print the value of content.
I want to print only 40 characters of this content on view page and then want to implement "read more" to go to full content page.

Comment: you can use `content.substring(0,40)` in your JS file

Comment: @Chandan but from js file, i am sending whole doc like.. res.write(loadView('bodylearnmorepage',{doc:docs}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing by the syntax, you are using Handlebars or some similar derivative. If it's not Handlebars, you'll have to modify the below a little to match your framework, but it should be similar. Leave a comment if it's not and I'll edit.

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#helpers) supports what is known as **helpers** which allow you to manipulate data fed into your views.

You could write a helper named, for example, `excerpt`, like so:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('excerpt', function(data, url) {
  if (data.length > 40) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(
      data.substring(0, 40) + '… <a href="' + url + '">Read more</a>"
    );
  }

  return data;
});
```

You can then use it like `{{excerpt this.content this.readMoreUrl}}`, where `this.readMoreUrl` is whichever property provides the relevant URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the JavaScript MVC but You can do something like this in JS:

```
content = this.content
if(content.length > 40)
  content_to_print = content.substr(0,40)
  content_to_print = content_to_print+' <a href="#">Read More...</a>'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your `if` statement is not legal Javascript syntax.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the correction. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Junaid: The problem , i am facing is on view page because i have to send whole doc on view page so i can print content along with title. so i don't think js side code will work.